# Issues with WiX, Visual Studio 2005, XP

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2005

An old Wix 2.0 Web project (.net 2.0, C#), needs to be brought up to date.

I just installed wix toolset 3.10. (I still have the wix 2.0 on this computer)

I have Visual Studio 2005 (8.0.50727.42 version 2.0.50727 SP2)

*I also have Visual studio 2008 installed (9.0.30729.4462 QFE, version 3.5 sp1), in case 2005 is not going to be enough, but I thought I will just not update the whole solution just yet, if I don't need to.*

All this on an XP Professional machine, version 2002, SP3

I am not able to see the WiX from either VS05 or VS08.

Can this work all together? Or I need to upgrade Visual Studio or the XP operating system?
Or maybe I should use an earlier version of wix?

Thanks

I tried searching for an issue like this, but have not find anything yet, hope it is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WiX v3.8 was the last version of WiX to support Visual Studio 2008.](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2013/09/27/visual-studio-2008-deprecated-in-wix-v3-8/)